# MYSQL stored procedure delete

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I have stored procedure:

```
BEGIN
SELECT @id_for_del := ful.social_id
FROM facebook_users_likes ful 
where
(select count(*) from facebook_users fu where fu.social_id = ful.social_id) = 0;
IF NOT @id_for_del IS NULL
THEN 
DELETE from facebook_users_likes WHERE social_id = @id_for_del;
END IF;
END
```

**Select** returns me 46 000 lines but delete only one line per execution stored procedure.
So, how to delete all 46 000 lines at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a direct translation of the `select` into a `delete`:

```
DELETE FROM facebook_users_likes ful 
WHERE (select count(*) from facebook_users fu where fu.social_id = ful.social_id) = 0;
```

It is more efficient to use `not exists` in this context:

```
DELETE FROM facebook_users_likes ful 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (select 1 from facebook_users fu where fu.social_id = ful.social_id);
```

This is especially true if you have an index on `facebook_users(social_id)`.